# I want to open git bash in a linux server using putty. How will I do that?

Tags: linux, git, putty

I am following this https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git and I am stack on step 5, I want to open git bash in a linux server using putty. How will I do that? In windows, there is gitbash cmd desktop app. But in linux how will you get from normal command line to git bash?

Note: I am using putty to access the linux server. If there is other way also, please recommend me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Windows gitbash is an emulation of a bash command interpreter designed for UNIX systems. On many Linux distributives bash is a default command shell. So, when you're connecting to a Linux via putty, you're actually entering a bash shell. There's nothing more you need. You can use it the similar way as you're using windows gitbash. In a nutshell, just omit the first item in the spet 5 of your tutorial: you probably already in the bash shell.

To check out which shell you're using, run this command: `ps -p $$`. It will output something like this:

```
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
10967 ttys000    0:01.68 -bash
```

The CMD field is the shell name you're using.

Comment: So how will I know if it is git bash from the above output?

Comment: You can check if git is installed on your Linux system by the `which git` command. If it will output something like `/usr/bin/git` - git is installed and you can use it. But if the output will be a blank line - then you have to install git on your Linux system first. You can install it via `apt-get install git` if your Linux is from Debian family, or by similar package management tool. But you must have an administrative privileges in order to install something on Linux systems.

Answer (score 4):

“Git bash” under Windows simulates a Linux environment (it uses MinGW behind the scenes, afaik).

Under a Linux distribution, you just have to have a version of Git installed. With a Debian based distribution you would for example run `sudo apt-get install git` (or `git-core` for older releases) on the command line.

Once installed, you can use it from the command line without further ado.